# Best way to set up a dev environment for Node.js using AWS s3?

Tags: node.js

We are getting ready to port part of our app over to node.js, and are looking for a way to support s3 uploads and testing in our development environment.  Right now we are thinking about setting up test buckets (ie 'myProductionBucket-test'), setting this in our dev environment configuration, and then creating a lifecycle rule to delete content after 24 hours.  This seems clunky though, wondering if there is are local alternatives we could run on our dev boxes that might work better.

Also, we're leaning towards node-config vs node-convict or just loading json.  Any thoughts there also greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** We've looked at https://github.com/jubos/fake-s3, and also thought about just mocking for tests, but it would be handy to put and retrieve the same files, since that's the basic function of the app. It seems crazy to pay amazon for running dev/test and production.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: We've prototyped it on an EC2 instance and hooked it up to our git repository.  Works great, put and get from s3 no problem.  Now we're scratching our heads trying to figure out the best way to recreate that on local environments so we can have multiple developers working on it.  Google/Stackexchange/SO and the amazon docs haven't yielded any options at all.  I'm sure we're missing something but we're a week of research into this and thought we must be missing something obvious.  If you want to use s3/SQS/Elasticache is there a way to simulate those in your dev environment?

Comment: Here's an example of a very similar question unanswered on amazon's forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=117500